# Why some airspaces don't have high-altitude IFR airways?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, flight-planning, aeronautical-charts

I noticed on enroute charts that some airspaces (mainly over Balnkans - e.g. LWSS, LYBA, LDZO, LOVV etc) do not have high-altitude IFR airways. Unfortunately searching online didn't reveal much. What could be the reason for that?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Image depicting the lack of high IFR airways (courtesy of Navigraph)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The areas without routes are the free route airspace of the [FAB-CE](https://www.fab-ce.eu/airspace/free-route) (functional airspace block Central Europe).

In this airspace, IFR flightplans are not bound to airways and routes can be planned to best suit the needs of the aircraft operators.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Further reading: https://www.skybrary.aero/articles/free-route-airspace-fra